# bootstrap grid with blank form-group col-md-6

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, frontend

I'd like to achieve a grid like down below. There's a problem because I've got form-group as well. And the problem is, col-md-6 before last and the last one doesn't align correctly.

```html
<form action="">
  <div class="col-md-1 pull-right text-right padding-right-0">
    <div class="action-buttons">
      <a href="#" class="pull-right button-edit-content" data-target="#s3">
        <i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </a>              
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label for="">label_1</label>
    <input type="text">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-5">
    <label for="">label_2</label>
    <input type="text">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label for="">label_3</label>
    <input type="text">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-5">
    &nbsp;
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label for="">label_5</label>
    <input type="text">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-5">
    <label for="">label_6</label>
    <input type="text">
  </div>
</form>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping them in row, like

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="">label_1</label>
        <input type="text">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-5">
        <label for="">label_2</label>
        <input type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="">label_3</label>
        <input type="text">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-5">
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I see what you're trying to do. I think the problem is the empty column which doesn't have a comparable height to the others.

I'd suggest removing that empty column and clearing the left of the following one by adding a class to it as in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vv807bax/

CSS:

```
.clearleft {
  clear: left;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<form action="">
  <div class="col-md-1 pull-right text-right padding-right-0">
    <div class="action-buttons">
      <a href="#" class="pull-right button-edit-content" data-target="#s3">
        <i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </a>              
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label for="">label_1</label>
    <input type="text">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-5">
    <label for="">label_2</label>
    <input type="text">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label for="">label_3</label>
    <input type="text">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-6 clearleft">
    <label for="">label_5</label>
    <input type="text">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-5">
    <label for="">label_6</label>
    <input type="text">
  </div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Or you can use bootstrap's clearfix: <div class="clearfix"></div>